# Is there a system table that lists all file groups?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

For example `master.sys.master_files` lists all files for all databases.
It also lists `data_space_id` which maps to the file groups.

But the `master.sys.filegroups` table only lists file groups used by the `master` database. Is there such a table where I can get all file groups across all databases?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/47414423-5c52-492e-88fd-d673c385f447/list-all-filegroups-for-all-databases-?forum=transactsql

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge there is not a single table or view which shows the file groups for all databases in the instance.

There is however a view called **sys.filegroups** in each database which will list the file groups for that particular database.

**Example**

```
USE [MyDatabase]
select * from sys.filegroups
```